# Timeout is more than I set in `java.net.URLConnection`

Tags: java, timeout, urlconnection

I'm trying to set a timeout for `java.net.URLConnection` as this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setConnectTimeout(2000);
con.setReadTimeout(2000);
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
doc = new Tidy().parseDOM(in, null);
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//td//span");
Node form = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

The problem is that while I set timeout to 2000 (2 seconds) it waits more than it (for example 20 seconds as I counted by myself) until throwing Timeout exception.

What is the problem?
How Can I set the timeout to work exactly at the value I set?

Answer (score 1):

The `readTimeOut` is not working in Sun's (Oracle's) implementation reliably. This is even mentioned in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29):

> Some non-standard implementation of this method ignores the specified
>   timeout. To see the read timeout set, please call getReadTimeout().

You can simulate timeouts using threads or timers though. Pass the connection to a child thread, and ask that thread to call `disconnect` or something similar after the timeout expires.

Comment: Hi,Thanks.But Sun's implementation is non-standard?!

Comment: Technically speaking Sun's Java is the "Reference Implementation" of the Java specification. And as it has passed the TCK, it is safe to say it is a standard implementation. I think that sentence in the JavaDoc is vague. It should have been something like "Java implementations are allowed to implement this method as a no-op" or something like that. By the way, are you sure you are reading anything from the input stream at all? Otherwise why should it timeout at all? Could you post a more complete block code that shows this behavior?